# How do I use jQuery's insertBefore() function with a javascript string of HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am performing some DOM manipulation once my page loads and I was hoping to add some html right before an a specific div on the page. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I'm sure there's a simple way to accomplish this...

```
var finalStringHtml = '<div id="chartLinks">' + tableString + '</div>';

$(finalStringHtml.html().insertBefore("#chart_div")); //fails
$(toString(finalStringHtml).html().insertBefore("#chart_div")); //fails
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `.html()` call. (full docs: http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

Try:

```
$(finalStringHtml).insertBefore("#chart_div");
```

If you want to, you can do the full code on one line and not create the variable:

```
$('<div id="chartLinks">' + tableString + '</div>').insertBefore("#chart_div");
```